# implementing a conditional into a function

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to put a conditional into a function. this is the original code

```
function do_meta_box( $meta_field_def, $key = '' ) {

$content      = '';
$esc_form_key = esc_attr( self::$form_prefix . $key );
$post         = $this->get_metabox_post();
$meta_value   = self::get_value( $key, $post->ID );

// other stuff

$content .= '<input type="text"' . $placeholder . ' id="' . $esc_form_key . '" ' . $ac . 'name="' . $esc_form_key . '" value="' . esc_attr( $meta_value ) . '" class="large-text' . $class . '"/><br />';

// other sutff
}
```

Now i'm trying to put a conditional where the value is.

```
$my_custom_title = get_the_title() . ' My Custom Stuff';
if (  $post->post_type == 'post'   ) { echo esc_attr( $my_custom_title ); } else { echo esc_attr( $meta_value ); };
```

Exactly right here: `value="' . esc_attr( $meta_value ) . '"`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you defined global variable $post?

Comment: @mevius found the answer already, and it works. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @Kamal , The better alternative to globalizing `$post` is to use the `$post` object that has already been returned...(i.e. `$post->title`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign it to a variable...

```
$value = $post->post_type == 'post' ? esc_attr( $post->title ) : esc_attr( $meta_value );

$content .= '<input type="text"' . $placeholder . ' id="' . $esc_form_key . '" ' . $ac . 'name="' . $esc_form_key . '" value="' . $value . '" class="large-text' . $class . '"/><br />';
```